# In Nest.Js How to send body with form data request and apply body request validation. File is optional to be attached

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multipartform-data

In Nest.js, when i want to send a request with form data that may or may not include a file attachment then i am not able to get both body request and file at same request and also validate the body request that fields are valid or not.

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  MaxFileSizeValidator,
  ParseFilePipe,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { JoiValidationPipe } from "../../pipes/validation/joi-validation.pipe";
import { UserValidatorSchema } from "./validator/account-register.validator";
import { CreateUserDto } from "./dtos/account-register.dto";
import { AccountRegisterService } from "./account-register.service";
import { FileInterceptor } from "@nestjs/platform-express";
import { MAX_FILE_SIZE } from "../../constants/multer.constants";

@Controller("user")
export class FormdataWithFileController {
  constructor(private readonly _formdataWithFileService: formdataWithFileService) {}

  @Post("formdataWithFile")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
  private async Signup(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
          new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: MAX_FILE_SIZE })
        ],
      })
    )
    file,
  ) {
    return await this._formdataWithFileService.execute(file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileIsRequired: false` is put in the @UploadedFile() Pipe to make file optional.

`@Body(new JoiValidationPipe<CreateUserDto>(UserValidatorSchema)) : body CreateUserDto)`  decorator will perform body validation.

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  MaxFileSizeValidator,
  ParseFilePipe,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { JoiValidationPipe } from "../../pipes/validation/joi-validation.pipe";
import { UserValidatorSchema } from "./validator/account-register.validator";
import { CreateUserDto } from "./dtos/account-register.dto";
import { AccountRegisterService } from "./account-register.service";
import { FileInterceptor } from "@nestjs/platform-express";
import { MAX_FILE_SIZE } from "../../constants/multer.constants";

@Controller("user")
export class FormdataWithFileController {
  //
  constructor(private _formdataWithFileService: FormdataWithFileService) {}

  @Post("formdataWithFile")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
  private async Signup(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
          new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: MAX_FILE_SIZE }),
          // new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: "image/jpeg" }),
        ],
        fileIsRequired: false,
      })
    )
    file,
    @Body(new JoiValidationPipe<CreateUserDto>(UserValidatorSchema)) body: CreateUserDto
  ) {
    // acccess file & body data
    const fileWithBody = {
      body,
      file
    };
    return await this._formdataWithFileService.execute(fileWithBody)
  }
}
```

Comment: `fileIsRequired: false` I was missing this key...

Comment: ok let me know if you are facing any other issue...